# Cookies to remeber javascript function

Tags: javascript, cookies

Can cookies remember javascript function ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store functions in cookies, since functions cannot be serialized to a string. However, this function does not look like serializing it would help in any way. Why do you need to do that? If you are trying to store a authentication state, then you should do that instead of trying to store functionality.

Comment: I need to be remembered authentication state. The thing is the login is made in iframe and above script changes css file(to change menu bar) and login in logout in parent page. Everytime I refresh parent its nasty to see how menu changes and Login changing in Log out.

Comment: Then why don't you store the authentication state in a cookie? You can read it's content on page load and execute that function afterwards.